# Convert varchar to datetime format

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, datetime-format

I am working on a data movement where the source is MongoDB and target is Redshift. There is a date column in a table and the datatype of that column is varchar. The issue I am facing is, I am getting the dates in 2 different format as shown below.

FORMAT 1:

```
Mon Apr 03 2023 10:05:01 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Tue Mar 21 2023 08:15:01 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Tue Mar 21 2023 12:45:01 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

FORMAT 2:

```
2023-08-01 10:20:15.243
2023-08-01 06:30:15.875
2023-08-01 10:10:15.250
2023-08-01 07:45:01.401
```

We are using Dbeaver as my sql tool and tried using the regex to remove the string part in the format1 and apply the same logic for the upcoming data as well but I am unable to get the correct query. I want to change the rows which are in the format 1 to format 2 and also I want the data in the format2 going forward. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET date_column = 
    CASE 
        WHEN date_column LIKE '%GMT%' THEN 
            TO_CHAR(
                TO_TIMESTAMP(
                    SUBSTRING(date_column, 5, 20), 
                    'Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
                ), 
                'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'
            )
        ELSE date_column
    END;
```

Please replace your_table and date_column with your actual table name and column name.

Also, please note that this query assumes that all dates in the first format follow the same pattern. If there are dates that do not follow this pattern, you may need to adjust the SUBSTRING function accordingly.

Comment: It is working, thank you so much.

Comment: If the above solved your issue then please ACCEPT the answer. Doing so aids future questioners with the same or similar questions and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Kindly do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.